# DatePicker is not working in Textview in Android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to display datepiecker in textview, but it is textview is not working. The code not shown any error but when run the apps, the date not come out. Here is my code for datepicker is like below:

```
TextView tv;
Calendar mCurrentDate;
int day, month, year;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto4);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

    mCurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    day = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    month = month + 1;

    tv.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
         public void onClick (View v)
    {

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(Tuto4Activity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                String date = "Date"+String.valueOf(year) +"-"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear)
                        +"-"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                tv.setText(date);
                tv.setText(date);
            }
        }, yy, mm, dd);
        datePicker.show();

        }

    });
}


public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    boolean checked = ( (RadioButton) view). isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButton1:
            if (checked)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto2);
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:
            if (checked)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto3);
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton3:
            if (checked)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto4);
            break;

    }

}

}
```

My question is how to make datepicker display in the textview? Please help me.

Comment: do you get any error...?

Comment: I didn't get any error

Comment: what do you mean by **how to make datepicker display in the textview?**

Comment: what I mean user can select the date by clicking the textview button, and then the calendar will be display and allow the user to choose the date. I got this code from youtube video..Here is a link of the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qdnoRHfAYU

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
 final int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 final int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 final int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


 DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(SearchResultClass.this,
                                  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {

         tv.setText(selectedyear + "-" + month + "-" + selectedday);

                    }
         }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

  mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

  mDatePicker.show();
```

Comment: @norafiqa using this code its workin fine in my device

Comment: I don't know why it cannot run in my device..no error displayed. You have another solution?

Comment: than i have no other solution @norafiqa

Comment: can u check my code in xml file below, maybe I do smthg wrong